# How to make it using the POST method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I read about `GET` and `POST` on the internet and I am quite confused about it.
I understand most of it but, I have few confusion like Should I use GET method to get (retrieve) the data from action page, we cannot change server data sing it (edit, delete, update) while post is used to just post the data on the server and we can do (edit, delete, update) with this.
Like I have following example I am confused on how to make it using POST method? And I have no parameter to pass in the url.
I also see, I cannot make it asynchronous.

```
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = "/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml"
         xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlhttp.send();
        //   alert(xmlhttp);
            var xmlDoc;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    //     alert(xmlDoc);
                } 
            }
```

When i use POST method for the above code i am getting error,

```
<title>The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml' is not allowed
```

Why so?

Comment: IN the above when i change method to POST it doesn't work. I just need to read an XML, while i don't want to make updation to any XML, so is it compulsion to use only GET in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = "/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml"
         xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlhttp.send(post_variable); //I have changed this
        //   alert(xmlhttp);
            var xmlDoc;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    //     alert(xmlDoc);
                } 
            }
```

then just make post_variable like this

```
post_variable=field_name=value&field_name2=value2
```

remember to encode values with **encodeURIComponent(value)**

so for example your string would look like this

```
post_variable = "name=" + encodeURIComponent("this is my name") + "&last_name=" + encodeURIComponent("this is my last name");
```

I hope this helps

I recommend you to start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) its lightweight and it will be much easier to use then your custom made scripts. So basically if you use jQuery you can do it this way

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml', //read xml
    type: 'post', //method type
    dataType: 'xml', //can be json, html, xml etc
    data: $('#form_id').serialize(), //this will collect form values
    success: function(d) { alert(d); } //this method will be executed once done
   });
```

and that is all, you don't have to worry about anything, about browser version, browser type, or similar things.

Comment: That is same as query string but you need to build it from form values.

Comment: I tought that it is clear from comments, just changed "dataType" to xml

Answer (score 2):

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: I am a more of .net developer, and i went through the link you sent me, and from there i put efforts for POST, but that don't work for me, is it essential to pass querystring parameter in the URL for POST method?

Comment: Getting Error <title>The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/TinyEditor/XML/PreviewBody.xml' is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

`GET` and `POST` are two methods for submiting data into a target page. You can do both of these from a `form element` in `HTML`. The `form child elements` and their values will be carried to target.

`GET` method will carry this data in a user viewable form, i.e it will append this data to the `target URL.` So ts not at all safe to send sensitive data using this method.

POST does the same as that of `GET`, but it is not viewable to user. `POST` will carry info not through the `URL`. So `POST` can be used to carry sensitive data (arguable :) )

Comment: ok, these are just used to submit the data to the target page. In my code you see i am reading the XML, using the GET method i thought i am using get that's why i can read the XML and get back in response, i can use POST there too? do i need to change just the first pameter by POST? if i do it then it don't work. Why so?

Comment: I dotm want to catche the data thats why i want to make it using POST.

Comment: However, i'm not clear to what u want to achieve, is it simply send an XML to some where? I mean data in form of XML?